# Lightbox 2 Caption (2nd line)

Tags: javascript, caption, lightbox2

My lightbox 2 gallery is working as it should. However, I would like to add a second line to the caption, below the line that is already there. I am a JavaScript novice so am struggling to work out how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you provide us with a non-working sample code, e.g. examples of what you’ve tried so far but hasn’t worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had another look at the 'problem' and managed to fix it without changing any JavaScript. I added an h6 tag to the title and p tag to the description within the caption and this created the 2 lines that I wanted.